# What is a good method for teaching weave poles?

Tags: dogs, training, agility

I know there are several ways to teach weaves, but I would like to know what methods have people used that have created consistent independent performance. I would like to be able to send my dog to the weaves from any angle and as far away as maybe 20 feet or so and still have my dog know that the job is to enter the first pole with their left shoulder first and continue on from there through all 12 poles without question. Ideally the method would also encourage bigger dogs to use a one footed style instead of hopping with both feet.

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent independent entries" ?

Comment: Thanks for asking... changed the question a bit. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

The best method I've used so far is the 2x2 method that Susan Garrett came up with. You can find the details here https://www.clickerdogs.com/2x2_weave_training.php

In the past I've used wires, cages, and "the weave pole dance" but those methods have taken much longer to train and I think that the entries are especially strong with the 2x2 system compared to these other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of 2X2 and wires.  After you  get to the dog doing 4 poles 2X2 I try a set of 6 with wires.  We went to a full set of 12 with intermittent wires and he learned very fast and kept up his speed n the weaves.

Comment: What do you mean by wires?

Comment: Wires are thin guides used to connect every other pole to help the dog stay in the correct weave pattern. They are a fairly old style training method. But they do help in some situations.